# Paramiko hangs on stdout.readlines() on some llinux devices but works fine on others

Tags: python-2.7, stdout, paramiko

I'm using paramiko to execute commands on another server and most of the time it works fine but for some servers it hangs after executing few commands.

I'd like to know how to troubleshoot and understand the issue.

this is the code I have.

```py
import paramiko 

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_ley_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy)
ssh = client.connect('hostname,username,password')
channel = ssh.invoke_shell()

stdin = channel.makefile('wb')
stdout = channel.makefile('r')


stdin.write(cmd+'\n')
stdin.flush()


#it hangs here
for line in stdout: 
    print(line)
```

Comment: 1) Do not use `invoke_shell` to automate command execution. 2) Do the commands produce any error output?

Comment: How to use stdin and stdout without invoke shell?? No errors at all

Comment: Show us your code that you use to check for errors + Show us how you execute multiple commands.

Comment: I’m using invoke shell to execute command “bash” with stdin.write(“bash”) and stdin.flush() and then execute second command the same way. I don’t know how to do it without invoke_shell() . I don’t have any specific error handling it’s just stuck when I do stdout.readlines() without displaying any errors

Comment: OK, so you **do not know** if the commands produce any error output? => read `stderr = channel.makefile_stderr('rb', bufsize) `

Comment: Strerr hangs the same way on readline . But I’m sure there are no errors with the commands because I’ve executed  them manually without any issues. The same script works fine on similar devices but Hangs on some of them.

Comment: The only way to continue is to close the stdout channel. Stdout.channel.close().. same with stderr.

Comment: Just because there are no errors when you execute the command manually does not mean there are no errors when you execute the commands in Paramiko. -- Anyway, try calling `set_combine_stderr(True)` before you start reading.

Comment: See [Paramiko ssh die/hang with big output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31625788/554319).

Answer (score 0):

You wrote a for loop to read output of some command which you executed earlier.
Is this command continuous running? If yes then you need to read buffer continuously.

Try to write read logic like 

`for line in iter(lambda: stdout.readline(2048), ""): 
    print(line)`

Because if you don't specify a size, it reads until EOF, that makes the script wait until the command ends before returning from read() and printing any output.
See this : [Paramiko, exec_command get the output stream continuously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31317198/paramiko-exec-command-get-the-output-stream-continuously/31942655)